# Upgrading OS from System recovery of other PC

Tags: windows-8, operating-systems, windows-10-upgrade, system-recovery

I have 2 PCs. one of which is operating on windows 10 and another on windows 8(activated).
I have to upgrade Windows 8 to Windows 10. So I tried downloading windows 10 from MediaCreation Tool which is officially provided by microsoft. But it is taking long time...
So to upgrade to windows 10 I thought to Create System recovery on my PC having windows 10 and copy it on my windows 8 PC and then restore it there...
Is this a good Idea? If anybody had tried this plzz guide me? Is there any risk to do this...?
Thank you!

Comment: The windows 8  to 10 free update period is over anyway.

Comment: media creation tool is still available @JourneymanGeek

Comment: Yup but the update process may not work. The MCT's mainly for new installs or updating to newer builds in 10

Comment: Oh Your goodness I m just commenting with upgraded Windows..@JourneymanGeek

Answer (score -1):

It wouldn't work. System recovery contain OEM key that glued to a bunch of hardware parameters, it will refuse to work on another PC. If both computers are the same models and have the same identical hardware you can try, but before doing that, make complete image of your hard drive, so in case of failure you would be able to restore it.